# How to part Pre-compile a ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

I have a website with huge number of pages, i keep pre-compiled version (with fixed naming) on production server.

Every time i make any change on my code i have to Publish the whole website just for a small change.

It takes about an hour to get the website published before i can deploy my changes to production server.

Is there a way to publish only a batch of pages so that the Publish process is faster?

Is there any other option to save the publishing time?

**NOTE:** By publishing I mean pre-compiling

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you confirm that it's a web site ? not a web app ? what are you modifying ? the template code (razor, webform) or c# ?

Comment: yes its a website that uses 3rd party Content Management System (Emerge)

Answer (score 0):

If you're modifying only the html tags (nto the server side tags) or css, you can deploy only the part you changed.

If it's compiled code you got no choice.

I think you might have to ask your self why it's taking an hour to publish your web site ? Is your compilation time that much long ? .

Comment: Pre-compiled asp.net is different, all the pages get put into assemblies and page place holders which don't contain the HTML/CSS/Server controls are left instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: its taking that much time to publish because its using 3rd Party Content management system and its size after compilation is 800 MB

Answer (score 0):

One method to reduce the compile time, and size of a web-site project is to split your website into several smaller and more maintainable sites.

You can still deploy these separate publishes together in production.

References to pages from other projects work perfectly. All your pages within the same application on IIS will share the same session. So to an end user, this will still appear to be one website.

Since you reduce the work to be done while publishing any given module publishes will be faster. Divide your modules as per what you see as a suitable batch.

You must be aware of this, but I will say it just for completion. When you publish a website you get the option,`Use fixed naming and single page assemblies`. Select this to have a different dll for each page in your bin directory. You only need to upload the pages and corresponding dlls where you made changes. If upload time is a concern, this will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but dividing it into modules is not an option for me and i am already using `fixed name assemblies`.

Comment: Why is it not an option? It is the simplest way to fix the problem.

Comment: I am using a 3rd party tool in the website that is very huge in size (around 500 MB) and that contains lots of ascx and aspx pages which i cannot move/change and that only is causing the Pre-compilation a time taking task

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't really have an idea of "pre-compiling" if you notice your pages have 3 components to them, the *.designer, *.aspx *.cs. The *.cs all needs to be compiled into a *.dll to be deployed to your website. Traditionally there are two types of executables, exe's and dll's. Asp.Net websites are compiled into a dll for all the code behinds that run on the server. Microsoft does not have a way to "half" compile a dll and then merge it with the other half you haven't changed.

If your website is taking that long, to compile & deploy. I would suggest you have more of an architecture problem then a code problem. Where I work our main website is 3,000,000+ lines of code, to accomplish everything the user needs to do and does. We don't take an hour to deploy. however what we have done is broken our business logic up into a number of dll's over 100 dll's and our website project in and of it self is just the aspx and the bare bones code behind to drive the flow through to our business logic. This allows us to alter x number dll's with our changes to support a new feature, We don't have to deploy all 100 dll's every time just the ones that have changed, that's the nature of dll's. if our business logic was 100% contained in our website project, then our compile, deployment would be significantly longer.

You want to consider refactoring your code into dll's. Another option if you're not married to the ASPX/ASP.NET solution is to consider an ASP/MVC.NET solution. I would consider refactoring your site. If it takes that long there's some serious issues, even if you could break Data access into a separate dll, then you wouldn't have to constantly compile & deploy the dll which handles your data access, every time you changed the website, only when you changed the Data access layer as well.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but all these points are already kept in mind while designing the architecture of website. My website contains 2000+ pages, controls, webparts, widgets. I already have separate dlls business logic and data access layers.

Answer (score 0):

As previous posts mention, you cannot do this in an automatic fashion, but you could manually deploy your files if you want to reduce your publishing time.

When publishing a website, all code files for your site are compiled into a single .dll file in the website bin folder and all .aspx files are be deployed to their relevant paths.

To update the site manually, simply build the website on your local machine to create an updated .dll and overwrite the .dll in the bin folder on the production server. If the source/HTML has been modified on any of your actual pages/.aspx files then you will also need to copy them over.

**Steps:**

1. Build website locally
2. Overwrite production server .dll with locally built .dll
3. Copy any .aspx pages to production server where HTML/Source modified

Comment: That is my question, how do i reduce the build time? I always build the site locally and deploy the dlls on production server

Comment: Surely it doesn't take hours to build it locally? My suggestion is to build it locally and manually copy over the required files rather than use the "publish" method.

Answer (score -3):

Very simple.

Have all the HTML content stored in separate files to the code. A database would be an excellent idea. All one would have to do to change some text or swap an image would be to go into the database or file for that content and change a few tags. I recommend MySQL.

:)